# Make windows go completely off screen in "show desktop" hot corner

Tags: desktop

Is there anyway to have it so when I go to the hot corner I have set to show desktop, the windows go so far off screen that neither them nor their shadow can be seen?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: just use spaces and go to another space by CTRL+rightarrow (CTRL+leftarrow to go back)

Answer (score 1):

That option is not available using the show desktop via hot corner.